# Python socket conn doesn't close on network change

Tags: python, sockets

I have a server that is connected to a socket on a cellphone.  I check if the connection is open by assigning the socket.recv() command to a variable and checking its length.  If its length is 0 then I close the connection.  Also if I receive any exception other than a socket.timeout exception I also close the socket (short example below).  This works well except for one situation.  When the phone which is the client changes from a wifi to a GSM network or visa versa, data stops being sent and received. However, the sockets on the and the cell phone server do not throw an exception, nor does it give a 0 length string to indicate the socket is done writing. They just continue as if nothing has happened.

The sockets persist until I manually close them.  Right now I'm doing this with a received data timeout, ie if I haven't received data in 2 minutes or more reset the connection.  However, I am wondering if there is another way to catch or prevent this from happening.  Is there a way to preserve a socket even when your network changes?

```
conn,addr=s.accept()
while True:
    try:
        message=conn.recv(1024)
        while len(message) > 0:
            #do something here
            message=conn.recv(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
    except:
        conn.close()
```